# Removing Powered By GetYourGuide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, widget

I am using a widget from Getyourguide.com in one of my online projects. Here's the widget code:

```
<div id="guide-display"></div>

<script async defer src="https://widget.getyourguide.com/v2/core.js" onload="GYG.Widget(document.getElementById('guide-display'),{'currency':'USD','localeCode':'en-US','partnerId':'MGXXXX','q':'London'});">
</script>
```

This code displays the widget, along with a powered by link at the bottom of the widget.

You can see the widget [here](https://jsfiddle.net/f6crobzq/).

Tried removing the link using various methods, but failed. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content is inside an iframe, on their domain, so you cannot alter it from your own domain thanks to CORS protection, which is a great thing. Imagine a website which displays a Facebook iframe, and accesses it to get info about you. That would be dangerous.

You can, however, put something in front of it. Like this:

```
#guide-display{
  position: relative;
}
#guide-display:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 20px;
  background: #fff; /* Or another color, depending on your website */
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yrcwvx8b/1/

**Disclaimer**: I think they wouldn't like you doing this. But I looked at their terms of use, they don't mention anything about altering/hiding the contents of their widgets. So you get the benefit of the doubt.

Answer (score 0):

You can render a div in top of the widget you want to hide

check this widget: [example](https://jsfiddle.net/vmu679td/1/)

```
 #hidder {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  height: 20px;
  top: -20px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

I made the div red to make it obvious